# signalr hub: Getting internal server error, Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: %

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

This is c# hub code:

```
[HubName("hitCounter")]
public class HitCounterHub : Hub
{
    private static int _hitCount = 0;    
    public void Recordhit()
    {
        _hitCount += 1;
        this.Clients.All.onHitRecorded(_hitCount);
    }
}
```

This is aspx body code:

```html
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <div id="hitCount" style="font-size: 200px;">
            abc
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>

    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var con = $.hubConnection();
            var hub = con.createHubProxy('hitCounter');
            hub.on('onHitRecorded', function (i) {
                $('#hitCount').text(i);
            });
            con.start(function () {
                hub.invoke('recordHit');
            });
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

I am getting following error on this page: "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: %. Path '', line 0, position 0."

[image]

Comment: assuming that the error is in the page you have shown your html, I don't think this is a signalr issue since signalr will be accessed via js and this seems to be caused by server side mark ups.

Comment: so can you narrow down the issue by removing the run at server form and then remove its contents line by line until you find if it is a line within the form showing an error

Comment: the call is not even going till server. control flow is not going inside "Recordhit" function

Comment: show more stack trace

Comment: I think you are using page templates or resolving path variable somewhere on server which is not able to parse the value of path due to slash or some other character please paste full code and stack trace. Its not hitting anyother function because exception is raised before going anywhere on server. This might be issue in your config file or routing etc.